# Python3:can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlCtH.png)I'm using chromebook that given by school. And I use Vscode to code my first program [print(Hello World)]. I exactly code that, but the terminal can't execute the program. I know that the school teacher closed some functions, but I don't know whether that affects Linux or my program.

I tried to open the other file and opened the Linux and Vscode again,but it didn't  change anything. I also copied the error message to the Google to search. But I didn't see the same situation.

Comment: Can you add more details ? How did you exactly run the python code? Chances are you are running the program from terminal and I am not sure if you have made sure to switch to the folder where your python file is located.

Comment: I add the screenshot in the question. thanks for your help

Comment: Can you try renaming your file to test.py and run the code with the said name?

Comment: please run this command "/home/sssh11235684/ptint(\"Hello World\").py". This works.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

When running a file name with Quotes in it, make Sure to add escape `\` character to be able to run the said file